# Flash: accessing high scores site raises security issues

Tags: flash

I have a flash game. I've been trying to connect it to a php website that uses a mySql db.

It works when I "test project" it from flash, however when I run it from a player/browser it raises errors about accessing a site.

I am looking for a work around:

1. What setting need I ask from my users to set in their flash player - I have personally looked for the right settings and found nothing about approving sites.
2. Is it possible that if both my game and my php site reside in the same base url - that is same server - that this error shall not appear? I really want to test this my self, but my server is a free server and doesn't allow me to upload certain files that are heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what error you are getting, but if it works locally but not on your server, it might be that you need to add a crossdomain.xml file. Just put a file such as [this one](http://pogopixels.com/crossdomain.xml) at the root of your domain and try again.

If that doesn't work, you should update your post with the error you are getting.

Comment: The error is: The following application: <game address> is trying to access the internet-enabled location <server address>. To let this application communicate with the internet, click settings.

The problem is that I haven't found such settings on the plash player - [I have flash player 10]. Thnak you.